# When does the absolute Galois group $G=\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$ of $K$ stabilize the maximal ideal in $\bar K$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K \supset \mathbb{Q}_p$ be the $p$-adic field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and maximal ideal $m_K$ and let $\bar K$ be algebraic closure of $K$ with maximal ideal $\bar{m}_K$. Consider the absolute Galois group $G=\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$.

> When does the absolute Galois group $G$ stabilize or fix the maximal ideal $\bar{m}_K$ ?

I wonder how this is possible. But I can describe one **possible** situation where it may happen:

Suppose we have a $p$-adic power series $f(x) \in \mathcal{O}_K[[x]]$ without constant term. So we can consider iterates $f^{\circ n}(x)$ of $f(x)$ and its roots in $\bar{m}_K$. So consider,
$$\Lambda_n=\{x \in \bar{m}_K~|~f^{\circ n}(x)=0\}.$$
Consider the field extension $L=\bigcup_nK(\Lambda_n)$. Thus $L$  is an algebraic extension.

Then $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ stabilizes the zero set $\Lambda=\bigcup_n \Lambda_n \subset \bar{m}_K$, and hence $\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$, at least, stabilizes the **infinite** set $\Lambda \subset \bar{m}_K$.

Am I right ? Please comment here.

But when does $\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$ fixes $\bar{m}_K$ ?

Will the assumption $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ being abelian help to answer my question ?

Thanks for any comments

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something here, I don't know much about $p$-adic stuff, but: doesn't the Galois group always fix the maximal ideal when the base field is complete? Because in this case there is a *unique* extension of the absolute value to $\bar{K}$.

Comment: Agreed with @leoli except they must mean "stabilize" not "fix". As for "fix", notice that for every element $x\in \bar K$, some $p^n x \in \bar m_K$, so if the Galois group were to fix them all ...

Comment: So: Stabilize, always; fixes, never; both for very basic reasons.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, so we have $(\sigma \circ \tau)(x)=(\tau \circ \sigma)(x)$ for all $x \in \bar{m}_K$ and for all $\sigma,~\tau \in \text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$.

Comment: No, why would we have that? -- In my comments, by "stabilizing" I mean $\sigma(\bar m_K) = \bar m_K$ or equivalently $\sigma(x) \in \bar m_K$ for all $\sigma \in Gal, x\in \bar m_K$; by "fixing" I mean $\sigma(x)=x$ for all $\sigma \in Gal, x\in \bar m_K$. If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, ok. I have a confusion here. As $Gal$ fixes $\bar{m}_K$, $\sigma(\tau(x))=\sigma(x)=x=\tau(x)=\tau(\sigma(x))$ for all $x \in \bar{m}_K$, because $\sigma(x)=x=\tau(x)$. Isn't it ?  Am I missing something ?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, If it is not true, then when would we have $(\sigma \circ \tau)(x)=(\tau \circ \sigma)(x) $ for all $x \in \bar{m}_K$ ?   Is it true when the extension $Gal(L/K)$  abelian ?  Thanks

Comment: Nitpicks: "The maximal ideal of $\bar{K}$" - this is the zero ideal (maximal ideal of a field) - it is clear what you mean, but you should define the correct thing. Strictly you should also be taking *an* algebraic closure.

Comment: As I said, Gal *never* fixes $\bar m_K$. leoli1 means "stabilize" when they say "fix" in their comment.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, yes thanks. Now it is clear to me.